# Degroup Week Aggregate into Date

Tags: sql, amazon-redshift

Having trouble finding a solution to this.

I have data with weekly totals that I want to break down to the date-level, where the totals are divided by the days in the week.

Starting Table

| Week | Amount |
| --- | --- |
| 2020-10-18 | 1000 |
| 2020-10-25 | 2000 |

Resulting Table

| Date | Amount |
| --- | --- |
| 2020-10-18 | 142.9 |
| 2020-10-19 | 142.9 |
| ... | ... |
| 2020-10-24 | 142.9 |
| 2020-10-25 | 285.7 |
| 2020-10-26 | 285.7 |

Thanks for your help.

Comment: I assume you are using Redshift and under the mistaken interpretation that it is similar to Postgres (or, say, more similar to Postgres than a random other database).  I removed the Postgres tag.

Answer (score 0):

Redshift makes it difficult to generate tables on the fly.  But 7 rows isn't so bad:

```
select week + n * interval '1 day', amount / 7.0
from starting s cross join
     (select 0 as n union all
      select 1 as n union all
      select 2 as n union all
      select 3 as n union all
      select 4 as n union all
      select 5 as n union all
      select 6 as n 
     ) n
```